# Chrome does not open Https websites

Tags: linux, fedora, chrome, ssl, https

I am a corporate user with proxy server. I am working on the Fedora 20 OS and installed Chrome browser.

I set proxy settings under Settings -> Network -> Change Proxy settings -> Network Proxy.

Where I have given my proxy setting in the HTTP Proxy.

PFA image [image]

But I am not able to access a website via HTTPS and It takes time to load and finally it returns website not found.

Do I need to change anything through system wide? If so, how?

Comment: It's is difficult to help you as we don't know your companys network setup. Perhaps you have to add the proxy also to the HTTPS proxy.

Comment: Yes.I have added the same in the HTTPS. But it ends up with a message "Your connection is private" with error code NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID. This issue only on the Chrome browser. On the same time, i can able to access in Opera without any issues. (In Opera, I get certificate alert box if i access https website). That too not happened in the Chrome browser.

Comment: Your HTTPS proxy inserts its own certificate. Some firewalls do this in order to perform layer-7 scans on HTTPS traffic. Chrome rejects bad certificates like that out of hand, Safari just warns.

Answer (score 1):

To enable browsing of HTTPS sites you have to add the proxy also to the HTTPS proxy settings.

Also you have to import the root CA of your companys proxy to chrome else chrome will not accept any connections as it does not know the root CA.

Also be aware that you will not be able to display some sites as chrome is using Certificate pinning for some sites (e.g. https://www.google.com).

The certificate pinning is done to prevent Man-in-the-Middle (MitM) attacks. Using a https proxy *is* basically a MitM attack as your secure connection is broken up at the proxy.